# How to add dot over elements of a matrix with latex?

Tags: matrix, latex

I want to write a matrix in latex, which has some elem with dot over them, for
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLOoK.png)

here is my source code(only snippet):

```
\documentclass{article}

% font 
\usepackage{ctex}           % for chinese 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters

% math 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages for equations
\usepackage{amssymb}    % for math symbol 
\usepackage{siunitx}    % for unit display 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \dot{a}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

but  I receive an Error Message:

```
Package amsmath: \dot allowed only in math mode.
```

My environment:

```
VSCode + texlive
```

Wanted to know if '\dot{}' is a good way to add dot over elements of a matrix? If not, what would be the right way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make a [mre]. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \dot{a} 
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}` compiles without error for me

Comment: @samcarter Thanks a lot for pointing out this. As I find out if I comment 'ctex', there will be no error message at all. It seems there are some conflicts. But as I also have to use Chinese in my article, how can I use both Chinese and matrix elem with dot?

Comment: I don't have the necessary fonts installed to test locally with ctex, but on overleaf your example seems to work without error: https://www.overleaf.com/read/mqztptqbhmbh

Comment: Oh, I solve it by myself (below is my solution). I have tried my source code on overleaf, and even with xelatex(the recipe I used in vscode), there is no error at all. Then I guess maybe some of my local latex packages don't have correct version ( maybe not same with package version ovearleaf uses), but even as I update all my local packages, the problem still exists. Then I give up, and try the solution below, and it magically works... However, thank you for your advice @samcarter, they help a lot.

Comment: Overleaf packages are NOT up to date, it can very well be that it worked in the old tex version used by overleaf but not with up to date packages. Maybe you can re-ask the question on tex.stackexchange.com. There might be more people able to help you. I already voted to migrate your question there, but the migration system on stackoverflow is utterly broken, so re-asking might be better.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I solve it! (not a clean solution, but a work one). I change package 'ctex' to 'xeCJK', which only provide Chiniese characters -- the exact thing I need -- without a lot of other features ctex provides. And it works well.

But I am still curious why ctex+amsmath has this issue...

Here is my revised source code:

```
\documentclass{article}

% font 
\usepackage{xeCJK}           % for chinese 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters

% math 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages for equations
\usepackage{amssymb}    % for math symbol 
\usepackage{siunitx}    % for unit display 

\begin{document}

is Chinese ok? 
中文可以吗？

\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \dot{a} 
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Thank @samcarter for his advice, they help a lot

Comment: Oh, crazy!... Indeed `\dot{}` is the correct syntax :)